# What derivatives are used for splines in SciPy.interpolate.interp1d?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to find out how the spline interpolation in `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` decides what the derivatives of the fitting/smoothing function should be.  From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html), I understand that `interp1d` fits a spline if an `int` (or `quadratic` or `cubic`) is passed to the `kind` keyword.

But if I'm not providing any derivative information, how does it decide what the derivatives are? I tried to follow the function calls in the source code, but this only got me to the cryptic `spleval` function, which just seems to call FITPACK. And I wasn't really sure how to find information about FITPACK from [their website](http://www.netlib.org/fitpack/)...

Comment: I misunderstood your question... Hard to find an exact explanation, but I am putting my money on zero derivatives at the endpoints, all others determined to ensure continuity of the derivatives. See the examples in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 2):

Spline derivatives at the knot points are not explicitly prescribed, they are determined by [continuity/smoothness conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Natural_continuity). I'll take the cubic case as an example. You give n x-values and n y-values. A cubic spline has 4*(n-1) coefficients, 4 on each of (n-1) intervals between the given x-values. These coefficients are determined from the following conditions:

- The spline must be continuous at each interior knot: this is (n-2) equations, as there are (n-2) interior knots. We want both pieces to the left and right of a knot to have the same value at the knot.
- The first derivative of the spline must be continuous at each interior knot: this is (n-2) equations.
- The second derivative of the spline must be continuous at each interior knot: this is (n-2) equations.
- The spline must match each of the given y-values: this is n equations.

The total so far is 4*n-6 equations for 4*n-4 unknowns. Two additional equations are needed; the most popular choice is to require the 3rd derivative to be continuous at the leftmost and rightmost interior knots (this is called the "not a knot" condition). Now we have a linear system of size 4*n-4, which can be solved for the coefficients.

---

The above should not be confused with [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation), which is where one prescribes the values of derivatives as well as of the function itself. This is a less common task, and to my knowledge, SciPy does not have a built-in tool for it.